# Tablesorter Number above 1000000

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

hi guy im wondering how to make the tablesorter work with nombers above 1000000 ando i use this format example: 1,000,000 the code that im usisng is the following but it just works with number under 1000000:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "digit",
    is: function (s, table) {
        var c = table.config;
        return $.tablesorter.isDigit(s, c);
    }, format: function (s) {
        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s);
    }, type: "numeric"
});
```

I don't knwo if this also has something to do about:

```
this.isDigit = function (s, config) {
    // replace all an wanted chars and match.
    return /^[-+]?\d*$/.test($.trim(s.replace(/[,.']/g, '')));
};`
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do anything special to make tablesorter work with numbers - no extra parser, no special code. [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/3872/).

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra']
    });
});
```

Comment: where should i put the code? i am using jquery table sorter can you please help me? –

Comment: [Here is a demo](http://jsbin.com/xofutapavoxo/1/edit) of a complete page. The above code is located at the bottom of the page within a `<script>` tag.